# change your ip in bind socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to change my IP while I use bind in socket but it gives me an error:

> socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its
>   context

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community. Please, add some code to your post in order to understand better your issue. Thank you

Comment: iirc I got that error yesterday when binding an IPv4 address with an IPv6 socket or vice versa, so that might be the cause of this error

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include any code so I assume you did it like so:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
#The port and IP are for the sake of example
sock.bind(('1.2.3.4', 1200))
```

You can't do that. When you bind a socket to an IP and port you "say" to that socket to listen and wait until somebody send something to that port. Of course you can't listen to a port on some other computer so it gives you an error.

If you still wish to change your IP you can use Scapy: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/

This tool very complex but here is the most basic way to change your IP:

```
from scapy.all import *
#again the IP is only for the sake of example
MyPack = IP(src='1.2.3.4', dst='www.google.com')
send(MyPack)
```

Congratulations! you have sent a packet with a different IP (pretty sure it's illegal though)